# ASP .NET MVC 3 - RequestEncoding and ResponseEncoding for a single view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I know that I am able to add the following to the web.config file in order to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

However, I only want UTF-32 for a single view, not all of them. How can I accomplish this? I know how to do it with my response:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["Content-Type"] += ";charset=utf-32";
```

But how to do it with my request?

**Edit**
By request, I mean the equivalent to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx. By specifying that attribute, it's possible to specify a request encoding.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you mean with "how to do it with my request?". Values in Request object are about your clients coming to your site. Do you want to make a server side request to a URL?

If you want to make a server side request you can put value to :

```
  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("domain.com");
  request.ContentType = "application/xxx; charset=utf-32";
  request.GetResponse();
```

**Edit:**
The values in the `Request` are determined by clients that request your URL. In the page you share, there is a `requestEncoding` attribute. But the description of the attribute says that it specifies **assumed** encoding. But it is clear that any request having  Accept-Charset in its Header, simply override your setting. By the way, building any architecture belongs `requestEncoding` setting is not recommended. If you are developing a multiuser or public application, you may not decide how Request shaped.

You can also do it with [UploadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploaddata.aspx) method of WebClient:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
byte[] responseArray = wc.UploadData("URL_TO_POST", System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("param1_name=param1_value&param2_name=param2_value"));
string responseText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
```

Comment: That's great. How can I use this as an equivalent to WebClient's UploadValues function?

Comment: I edited the answer with WebClient version. But you can set Content-Type parameter when using UploadData method, not UploadValues.

Comment: With the new solution, it works fine with UTF8 (but with loss of characters). As soon as I change to UTF32 it gives an error 500 on the server. I tried putting a breakpoint. It doesn't even get to the first line in the controller of that URL.

Comment: Mathias.. I answered what you asked first about setting header for Request object. Now you have a different issue about Encoding. Please ask a new question or try to process your project yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding of the request is decided by the client - a browser, a call to jQuery ajax(), or some app. The only thing you can do about request encoding is hope that the client performing the call/request has the decency to tell your server about its encoding correctly.

Comment: The link that you provided only specifies the **assumed** encoding for when the client does not tell you what encoding it provides. It is still a fact that it is **the client** that provides this. Besides, what is the problem that you need to solve?